# How to disable/enable prefetching in GCC?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

Does -O3 enable prefetching in GCC? If so, how can I disable prefetching? Is there an option to control the "aggressiveness" of prefetching? For example, the amount of data to prefetch in each iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to GCC's [Data Prefetch Support](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/prefetch.html) website currently possible options are:

> Existing data prefetch support in GCC includes:
>
> - A generic prefetch RTL pattern.
> - Target-specific support for several targets.
> - A `__builtin_prefetch` function that does nothing on targets that do not support prefetch or for which prefetch support has not yet
>     been added to GCC.
> - An optimization enabled by `-fprefetch-loop-arrays` that prefetches arrays used in loops.

Then looking into [Optimize Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.1/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) it looks that `-fprefetch-loop-arrays` needs to enabled expicitely (that is, it's not enabled even with `-O3`).

> If supported by the target machine, generate instructions to prefetch
>   memory to improve the performance of loops that access large arrays.
>
> This option may generate better or worse code; results are highly
>   dependent on the structure of loops within the source code.
>
> Disabled at level `-Os`.

Note that [GCC's C99 status page](https://gcc.gnu.org/c99status.html) claims, that it currently does not take into account C99 `static` keyword for arrays in context of function declarator (C99 6.7.5.3/7). That means that "large array" size and what it really means is controlled solely by implementation.